# Bokeh plots distorting nbviewer slides view

Tags: python, git, matplotlib, plot, bokeh

When using the web based iPython Notebook/Jupyter capability, i created a notebook with markdown cells of text and code cells to display the code and plots for matplotlib and bokeh. I then download that as .ipynb open with sublime, copy and paste to git, then access it on nbviewer through my git account. When looking at it here:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/angisgrate/test/blob/master/pyohio3.ipynb
in notebook view, it works fine. the markdown, code, and plot steps are all there.
When switching to slides view, the intent of the creation needed for the presentation, this code blocks occurs first, blocking out the first 10 markdown steps and all the matplotlib steps, rendering this weird code without the plots:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/format/slides/github/angisgrate/test/blob/master/pyohio3.ipynb

How can i fix this asap?? I've looked through and there was a similar problem in 2014 with slides, but it yielded an actual "Error" that i'm not seeing, just this contorted view

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain. It's possible in the nbviewer slides view, the execution of JavaScript is suppressed (this happens on GitHub notebook previews, for instance). All of the rendering in Bokeh actually happens from the JavaScript library BokehJS, so if this is the case, then Bokeh will not function, and there is nothing really that can be done. This is probably a question bset directed towards the nbviewer team/community to find out the specifics of how the slides view behaves (and is intended to behave) with respect to executing embedded JavaScript.

**Edit**: Looks like this is a known/discussed issue. More information here:  [Issue #484: Jupyter>>nbviewer slides Fail, notebook view fine by angisgrate in jupyter/nbviewer on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/484)

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/484 Yup I created that issue and it is still open. They are working on it. Thank you